# how to add the Authentication-Results header with opendmarc

Tags: postfix-mta, email-headers

I am using `postfix`, `opendkim`, and `opendmarc`. Everything seems to be working well except the Authentication-Results header is not being added. I am only getting this header:

```
DMARC-Filter: OpenDMARC Filter v1.3.1 mydomain.com 9CAD616400E
```

Is there some setting that I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my own answer.  Hopefully this will help someone.

I was also running amavis and amavis was somehow controlling the Authentication-Results header.   I fixed this by changing this setting from 1 to 0 in the amavis.conf

$enable_dkim_verification = 0

Now opendmarc is posting 3 Authentication-Results headers as expected, One for dkim, one for spf, and one for dmarc